# Problem with UIScrollView and keyboard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, iphone-softkeyboard

Let's see: i have to views each with a couple of textfields.

One was built regularly, the other one has more textfieds and components so i added a scroll, which works (sorta). The problem is that, now, when i touch one of the text fields the keyboard appears and it hides the components, it doesn't scroll "naturaly" like in the regular view with no scroll (there, you know, the keyboard appears and the view "moves" in order to show the active text field).

So how can i accomplish that from my scroll?

I hope i've been clear, i'm an iOS newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer should be found here.

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: Thanks alot! I didn't searched for anything that simple and there you go, exactly what i needed.